# How to restore my dell 15 3542 OS to ubuntu?

Tags: restore

I am new to ubuntu. I have a brandnew Dell Inspiron 15 3542 with I3 processor, 4GB RAM, 500 GB HD with ubuntu 12.04 LTS preinstalled.
I updated ubuntu 12.04 then upgraded it to ubuntu 14.04 later I installed windows 7. how to set it back to factory settings.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I install Ubuntu?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/6328/how-do-i-install-ubuntu); before installation remove all partitions from the disk.

Answer (score 0):

It is generally better to make a clean install of ubuntu, rather than messing with the factory settings. Moreover, the factory version will be for 12.04 which is pretty old, the current stable is 14.04 LTS. If you already have Windows 7, you can use [unetbootin](https://unetbootin.github.io) or a similar program to create a bootable usb disk for ubuntu 14.04 LTS. Then, all you have to do is boot from that pen-drive and make a clean install of ubuntu 14.04 on your Inspiron laptop.